# Ruby on Rails: How should I seed my database with account specific data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a SAAS app using Rails 3. When a user creates a new account, the database needs to populate with a lot of data. Some of the data will be specific to the newly created account. I don't necessarily want to do this all with Models within the controller "sign up" action. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of things you should be using a callback within your User model. Most likely: a `before_create` or `after_create` (depending on your exact needs). You can then have the user model handle the creation of the account specific data, rather than your controller and thus adhere to the ideals of 'fat-model, skinny-controller'.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :setup_account_data

  private
  def setup_account_data
    # create other data as required
  end
end
```

Pretty simple really, after the user model is created - the `setup_account_data` method will be called. A list of the other available callbacks is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of approaches come to mind.

1. simple ruby.  This is similar to what is done when you run rake db:seed -- execution of a ruby script.
2. fixtures.  If you dump a database to fixtures [http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4468], you can modify the fixtures so that the data that needs to be customized is done in erb blocks.  This is the same technique that is used often in test fixtures.